# Cakephp retrieves pages over limit

Tags: php, cakephp, paginator

I'm using cakephp 1.3 paginator, it works fine, except for this:

if I have 5 pages, accessing by this kind of url

http://example.com/blog/5

I'll get the last page, but if I access to

http://example.com/blog/10

I also get the **last** page. But I want to not retrieve any values, since is not a valid page.

My configuration is like this:

```
  var $paginate = array(
        'Post' => array(
            'limit' => 10,
            'order' => array('Post.id' => 'desc')           
        ) 
    );

$posts = $this->paginate('Post');
```

Comment: Are you directly writing page number in url. Because cakephp pagination will show only exact number of pages

Comment: Yes, I'm writing the number, for testing purpose, even if this shouldn't happen, the fact is that the crawlers can find this kind of urls, so I don't want to have multiple urls with the same content, for SEO is too bad

Comment: May be this resolve by set max-limit attribute of pagination to limit . try it and check

Comment: I can't do it with max-limit because I don't know the total number of rows (unless I do a query, which obviusly I don't want to do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that's unfortunately how it works [**until CakePHP 2.3**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/components/pagination.html#out-of-range-page-requests), and it's buried in the middle of the `Controller::paginate()` method:

**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3.20/cake/libs/controller/controller.php#L1214-L1215**

```
// ...

if ($page === 'last' || $page >= $pageCount) {
    $options['page'] = $page = $pageCount;

// ...
```

So you pretty much have only one option, [**calculate the page count**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/1.3.20/cake/libs/controller/controller.php#L1203-L1212) yourself and use it to validate the current page.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is interested in this question for cakephp 1.3, I'll explain my solution based on @ndm answer.

The scenario is the following

- Paginate method isn't working well, so I need to rewrite it
- I don't want to update cake\controller.php file, because when I update the version with the last 1.3 branch (if ever happens) I would have to refix it, and the problem is that I probably will forget to do it.
- I don't want to code the fix in the app_controller, because the pagination method too long and the code feels noisy.

So I decided to create an new PageController which will extend the Controller class, and will extended by the AppController.

In this file I put the WHOLE paginate method, and make a single and easy fix, just before the point @ndm mention:

```
        if ($page >= $pageCount)
        {
            return array(); //return empty array, so no rows found.
        }

        if ($page === 'last') {
            $options['page'] = $page = $pageCount;
        } elseif (intval($page) < 1) {
            $options['page'] = $page = 1;
        }
```

Finally I used include to help the AppController found the PagerController:

```
<?php
include("pager_controller.php");

class AppController extends PagerController
{ 
     .....
}
```

And it worked perfectly, I would be able to update the cakephp 1.3 version (again if ever happen) without hesitating, and also not seeing the coding for the ugly paginate method.

Hope it could helps you